# Pepper plants slow growth and black parts of stems?

Tags: peppers

I have 4 pepper plants ([Syngeta Barbie F1](https://www.syngenta.hr/en/barbie-f1)) in raised bed together with 4 cherry tomato plants. Both peppers and tomatoes were planted as seedlings and while tomatoes have grown significantly and have fruits, peppers are almost same height as when bought (~30 cm). (I've put shading net above raised beds (more as protection from hale and heavy rain) but I think all plants gets enough sunlight and water).

All four plants have flowered and look healthy but they seem to be stagnating. I've also noticed that parts of stems are dark (like in the picture below - not actual picture).

[image: black parts of stems]

Is this normal and is there anything I can do to help them?

Comment: I find pepper plants more difficult to growth (much more sensitive on water and temperature), and in any case slower than tomatoes. Just wait (or you can prune away many flowers and branches, if you want earlier peppers).